# How to check a typedef'd obj in Objective-c NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I've got an method that takes NSDictionary arg. This NSDictionary has some predefined keys it'll take. All the obj's should be strings. But only certain string objs are valid for each key.
So my approach was to typedef NSString for each valid string per key. I'm hoping not to extend the NSString class.

I've typedef'd some NSString's...

```
typedef NSString MyStringType
```

Then I define a few...

```
MyStringType * const ValidString = @"aValidString";
```

Here's what I'd like to do in my sample method..

```
- (void)setAttrbiutes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
  NSArray *keys = [attributes allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
      if ([key isEqualToString:@"ValidKey"]) {
        id obj = [attributes objectForKey:key];
        //Here's where I'd like to check..
        if (**obj is MyStringType**) {
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I'm open to other ideas if there's a better approach to solve the obj type problem of an NSDictionary.

Comment: I think you want too much.  Either define a special class to represent your keys or compare the key values to a list of valid ones (possibly in an NSSet).

Comment: @HotLicks You're probably right. Even though NSSet probably doesn't add much weight I was trying to avoid extra objects if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work like that;  typedefs are a compile time alias that don't survive being passed through a dictionary.

In any case, using typedefs for something like this would be unwieldy.

I suggest you create a property list -- either as a file in your project or in code -- that contains the specifications of your various keys and valid values, then write a little validator that, passed a string and value, can validate the string-value pair for validity.

This also gives you the flexibility to extend your validator in the future.  For example, you might have a @"Duration" key that can only be in the range of 1 to 20.

Comment: It's actually for an ios library. I like the approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up a `typedef` for you special values, one possible option would be to create an `NSSet` of the special values. Then in your code you can verify that the object in the dictionary is in your set.

Answer (score 0):

What about a combination of category on NSString + associated object?

Something along the lines (untested!!):

```
@interface NSString (BBumSpecial)
- (NSString *) setSpecial: (BOOL) special ;
- (BOOL) special ;
@end
```

and:

```
@implementation NSString (BBumSpecial)

static void * key ;

- (NSString *) setSpecial: (BOOL) special {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, special ? @YES : @NO, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN) ;
    return self ;
}

- (BOOL) special {
    id obj = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key) ;
    return obj && [obj boolValue] ; 
}
@end
```

Which you could then use as:

```
NSString * mySpecialString = [@"I'm Special" setSpecial:YES] ;
```

?

Comment: That'll be slow, but likely work.  Note that you should always prefix category methods with something.  As well, category methods mean you are effectively interleaving your code with framework code, often leading to layering violations.

Comment: Honoured your comment! :-)

Comment: I hope you didn't take it as harsh criticism.  Just some comments.  It is neat code and, frankly, I think some means of "tagging" objects in a general purpose fashion might be desirable.   It becomes rather tricky when you have singletons.  Example: `id a = @"foo"; id b = [a copy]; [a setSpecial:NO]; [b setSpecial: YES];` is unlikely to do what you want. :)

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that associated objects are tricky with strings, given that strings are often static or shared references, so you're mucking with an object that may be used differently elsewhere.  Though probably not a problem in this case.